# What's the point to close a question as a duplicate after an answer was posted?

Tags: discussion, closing, exact-duplicates

For instance, I've voted to close [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280882/a-injective-endomorphism-over-an-artinian-module-is-an-automorphism) as an exact duplicate, but now there are two answers added and one is already accepted. What's the point to close it now?

Comment: There is no point, other than the minor point to discourage people asking it again in the future.

Comment: Or to encourage people to use search before posting?

Answer (score 6):

It the questions are actually duplicates, the answers can be merged into one question.  The acceptance on the closed question will be lost, and the OP on the original question can accept one of the merged answers if they wish.

Comment: @YACP An answer can always be un-accepted, and another answer accepted in its place.

Comment: @5PM You are right, but sometimes the OP of the previous question is gone. I guess that in this case the first accepted answer remains accepted.

Comment: @robjohn I think the right question is: who will merge the two questions? The moderators? If yes, can we announce them about this in order to merge it?

Comment: @YACP: the moderators do the merging when flagged and feasible. Flag a mod if you have concerns about merging.

Answer (score 6):

Closing the question means no more answers will be allowed to it.  If it is closed as a duplicate, there is also a link where a potential additional answer may be placed.