# Permanent flag-ban without warning.

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderation

I've flagged some posts and comments and nothing happened.

**Edit 1.** An update after correspondence with the The Stack Exchange Team about my flag-ban:

- As people thinks here ([Permanent flag-ban without warning.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9499/why-have-my-last-few-flags-not-been-acted-upon?noredirect=1#comment34684_9499)) it seems that I've been banned from sending flags to moderators. Is there anything you can do in order to reset my flag weight?

> Yes, you likely are flag-banned. You've had nearly as many flags declined as you accepted! Indeed, you seem to have gone out of your way to make a nuisance of yourself using the flag system, repeatedly flagging the same posts when you were unhappy with the outcome of your previous flag.
>
> Convince the moderators on Math.SE that the site would benefit if they were able to see more flags from you, and I'll lift the ban. Otherwise, you'll just end up in the same situation again in a week.
>
> -The Stack Exchange Team

- What do you mean by "Convince the moderators on Math.SE that the site would benefit if they were able to see more flags from you"? Are you expecting a request for lifting this flag-ban from one of the moderators?

> The thing to do would be to edit your meta question to indicate that you understand you have been flag banned, and explain to the moderators how you'll make certain that your flags will be accurate and not simply noise in the future if the ban is lifted. If the moderators indicate agreement, we'll lift the ban.
>
> That's the best we can offer you - there's no codified help once you reach the level that you have - **the ban is not designed to be escaped as it's an absolute last resort**.
>
> Regards, Stack Exchange Team

After this I gave up. **Let me say that never ever someone sent me a warning mentioning the possibility to be flag-banned if...**, that's why I think this "absolute last resort" must be a joke.

**Edit 2.** A moderator told me once: [If the questions are actually duplicates, the answers can be merged into one question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8228/whats-the-point-to-close-a-question-as-a-duplicate-after-an-answer-was-posted) **After this I've flagged many duplicates in order to be merged, but other moderators found this inappropriate and rejected my flags.** At that moment I had no idea where to look to see what's going on with my flags. Furthermore, I had no idea that some amount of rejected flags leads to a permanent ban.

I can survive with or without this ban, but it's better to make it public in order to let other users to know the "subtleties" of the system.

Comment: There is a flag hellban where mods won't see your flags anymore, but that one is extremely hard to hit. If you have around 10 more declined flags than valid flags, this might be the case.

Comment: You're close enough that I still think this is the case, but I'd need an SE employee to be sure.

Comment: I had a moderator act on a flag of mine yesterday, so moderation is not suspended.  (Why would it be?  The current moderators are still moderators, even those that have stated their intention of resigning but still have their diamonds.)

Comment: I have handled quite a few flags these last few days, and I do not recall seeing any from YACP.

Comment: Really... the idea that moderation is suspended is rather weird, isn't it? Don't you think if for some reason this had been the case we would not at the very least let the site know? Maybe you can rephrase your title/question in a way that does not suggest such silly behaviour on the part of mods and everyone else involved?

Comment: «Why have my last few flags not been acted upon?»

Comment: Anarchy on MSE...

Comment: For the record, several comments (and an answer with tons of comments) have been deleted by their owners here: that is why the comment thread is as random as it is...

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Why think this is anarchy? This is just a discussion.

Comment: @YACP This was a response to the presumed suspension of law and order on MSE under the original title.

Comment: +1 Because I was surprised to learn about flag-hellbans. These seem like a legitimate problem.

Comment: Dumb question, how do people tell whether the flags have been declined?  I can't seem to find that info anywhere.

Comment: On your user profile you should see a number saying "helpful flags: $x$", where $x$ is the number of flags that you raised and been marked helpful. If you click that number you are magically transported to the list of flags that you have raised, their status and some basic statistics about your flagging history.

Comment: @AlexBecker Flag bans are a legitimate problem, or the behavior leading to a flag ban is a legitimate problem?

Comment: @ScottH. Flag bans. (Although the behavior leading to them could certainly be as well.)

Comment: @AlexBecker Assuming that a user is abusing the flagging system (and I'm not making that assumption for this particular case), then what is problematic about suspending their flagging ability?

Comment: @ScottH. According to Mad Scientist's answer, it's not a suspension; it's irrevocable.

Comment: @AlexBecker The correspondence in the parent post indicates that an appeal can be made to the moderators of the site in question.  In any case, I would argue that a perma-ban is better than doing nothing at all, but I have little stake in the matter.  You, as a potential moderator, would be the one who has to deal with all of this.

Comment: Is there a good way for me to see if I've been flag hell-banned? I think Bill declined a bunch of my flags during the big cheating scandal.

Comment: @NoahSnyder, we had a big cheating scandal?  I remember a previously unheard-of contest doing very well by going the "zero cost, zero effort" security route and then benefiting in all kinds of ways when people here shouted for MSE to absorb some of the actual cost of those decisions.  It did not sound like much of a scandal, but maybe you refer to different events.

Comment: @zyx and Noah: Please try to stay on-topic!

Comment: @Noah: Take a look in the flagged summary and see what's the ratio of helpful to declined flags. If the ratio is close to 1:1 then it's possible.

Comment: @YACP: I thought my question was on-topic. I have a large number of declined flags from tht incident and so may be hell-banned. I'd like to know if I can find out if I have been or not.

Comment: @AsafKaraglia: Yes it's close to 1:1.

Comment: @Noah: I would advise you to contact a moderator and see if they even receive your flags, and if not you should contact the SE team and explain the situation.

Comment: @NoahSnyder My appeal was to not start talking about that "cheating scandal", and has nothing to do with your previous comment.

Comment: Btw, I find it interesting that none of the moderators, otherwise very active on meta, want to comment/answer my question.

Comment: Your editing has caused many comments to become irrelevant. I'm surprised the Team suggested you edit the question. I would have thought a better idea would be email to a mod, asking the mod to look over your flagging history to see whether the mod would ask the Team to lift the ban, or to discuss what modifications of your flagging methods might be in order should the ban be lifted. Must be better to hash this out in private than in public. Not much us non-mods can do for you.

Comment: @Gerry: I can lift the ban easily enough, but I'm not gonna do that if it's gonna make more work for the mods (which the flag history would suggest). The whole flag hell-ban notion is going away shortly anyway since we're re-working that entire system - so I'm not much inclined to step in unless there's a good reason to do so. Much easier to hash it out here given the discussion was already underway.

Comment: @Shog9 As my flag history suggests the whole story has behind the stubborness of moderators to keep alive the duplicates by not merging them with the original question. Maybe you should convince them (at least the new ones) that there is no reason to have more answers to the same question spread into 2 or 3 topics. Or maybe say it clear: **the admins of MSE are against of the merging of duplicates**. But having an unclear politics about things like these is good to create confusion between the users and/or moderators, don't you think?

Comment: "I can lift the ban easily enough, but I'm not gonna do that if it's gonna make more work for the mods." @Shog, that's why I suggested OP discuss flagging with the mods. If the discussion results in the mods feeling happy with unbanning, they recommend it to you, and you do it; if not, not. (Or, we just wait for the re-working of the system, when the problem disappears)

Comment: @YACP: maybe, instead of repeatedly flagging things, you should bring up the topic of dup-merging here for the community to discuss?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're almost certainly flag-hellbanned. This is a rather drastic defense against users with a terrible flag record. The details are rather complicated because it is based on the flag weight which users and mods can't see anymore.

This means that moderators simply won't see any of your flags anymore. There is no way to get out of this hellban. The original idea as far as I know was that you could still recover if you flagged posts that other users flagged as well or acted on, but that was never implemented. I assume that SE developers could also manually reset your flag weight, so there is still the option to contact SE directly (via a mail to team@stackexchange.com).

[This system is going away and will likely be replaced by blocking users for a short time when to many flags are declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/151385).

Comment: Uh, IIRC you _can_ get out of the hellban by flagging something that's also been flagged by other users, if the moderators then mark that flag as helpful.

Comment: @badp That doesn't work, but that was the intended way out that I mentioned.

Comment: This answer seems to be obsolete. For instance, I I think have at least a reasonable flag record and at present I cannot flag anything. If this isn't a bug, then something new has happened.